# (node.js) install NPM and YARN alternately

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, yarnpkg, npm-package

Can I install NPM and YARN alternately?

If I need package a and package b, can I install package a with NPM and package b with YARN?

```
npm install a
yarn add b
```

Comment: you can, but shouldn't.

Comment: Vote on [this proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354583/disentangle-the-yarn) to ease the tag confusion around [yarn] and [yarnpkg].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Yarn](https://www.sitepoint.com/yarn-vs-npm/) is fine alone, and I don't see personnally why you need use both for a project. But yes, you can install both in the same project.

In case you would like to see the advantages of Yarn over Npm, I'll slip you this little link: https://www.sitepoint.com/yarn-vs-npm/

Comment: There is no special reason. However, I have only used NPM, so I accidentally installed some packages with NPM, so I was worried about a crash. Thank you for answer.